# Why won't ActionResult persist record to Database?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So, I have a fairly simple Model with a fairly simple controller.  My view successfully passes the `TabularData` record to the Controller.  It goes through the motions of adding to the context, then appears to `SaveChanges`.  It doesn't error or anything.  Yet, when I check the database, the record doesn't exist in the table.  I can't for the life of me figure out why.  If I try to insert the same record again, it gives me a key violation error.  I'm sure my Model is connected to the right database, because if I insert a record into SQL, it shows up when I query the table in VS's Server Explorer.  It seems like such a simple operation, but I'm scratching my head trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong...

Here's my Model:

```
namespace ReflectionProject.Models
{
    public class TabularData
    {
        [Key]
        public string User { get; set; }
        public string Choice1 { get; set; }
        public string Choice2 { get; set; }
        public string Choice3 { get; set; }
        public string Choice4 { get; set; }
        public string Choice5 { get; set; }
    }

    public class SandboxDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<TabularData> TabularDatas { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here's the Controller:

```
namespace ReflectionProject.Controllers
{

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private SandboxDBContext db = new SandboxDBContext();
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public string Index(TabularData td)
        {
            db.TabularDatas.Add(td);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return "Thanks!";
        }
    }
}
```

One other note for the record: If I try to insert the record again through the web app, it throws a key violation.  Yet, if I manually insert the record in SQL Server, it doesn't complain.  And again, I'm sure the model is pointed to the correct DB.

Comment: try adding this to your key field instead of just [Key]  `[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`

Answer (score 1):

You are using `User` as your primary key.  This is going to add a unique constraint to the table.  By your current design you can only have one record per user.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine.  It's a Sandbox test solution, so I'm cool with that for the sake of stuff.  But, I still can't figure out why the record won't save.

Comment: Well, it has to be because if I go to Server Explorer, I can see my database, my table, and it queries with the live data.  If I insert a record through SSMS, I can go back to VS, say "Show Table Data," and there's my data.  Unless there's something between the Model and the Data that's askew?  But, shouldn't DbContext be handling all that automatically?

Comment: What is the correction string?  Is it `DataSource=(localdb)` by chance?

Comment: `<add name="SandboxEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Sandbox.csdl|res://*/Models.Sandbox.ssdl|res://*/Models.Sandbox.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=Sandbox;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

Comment: This is ridiculous.  EF is WAY more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: And, learning it isn't too bad... but, it's frustrating when you consider that in a couple years there's gonna be some other crap that's gonna make MVC and EF obsolete, and we're all gonna be entry level again.

Comment: @Hill - you are using Code First but have a connection string used by the designer. You need to change it to a standard sql connection string. http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/sql-connection-string/

Comment: @Hill - yes, you need to stay up to date on advances in your field. If this is difficult for you then I recommend you rethink you decision to work in anything having to do with the (generic term) tech sector especially coding.

Comment: There is a reason I just design my database with my database tools and skip this mess called code first.  But it seems I'm in the minority so the new EF7 tools are going to suck for me.

Comment: @Igor - Um, excuse me, but I'm not talking about "staying up to date on advances in your field."  I'm talking about the tendency for Microsoft to stay completely out of touch and unnecessarily complete shake up an entire sector of their business.  What your saying is not a good apology for the ridiculous learning curve and unnecessary complexity that comes with .Net MVC (and its related components).  I'm still under the mindset that you can build a great, scalable application much easier in Web Forms.  I honestly think the powers that be at Microsoft like to keep it complicated to protect jobs

Comment: @Igor - I have read or seen NOTHING that leads me to believe the benefits in MVC over Web Forms outweighs the complexity.  Nothing.

Comment: @Igor - I guess all the people who are unhappy about being required to upgrade to Windows 10... they're unjustified in complaining too, because they should be required to "stay up to date on advances" in home computing, right?  Whatever the Microsoft Gods say... if it comes from MS, it must be good.

Comment: no one is "required" to update to windows 10.  It is currently free for windows 7 and 8 users and highly recomended but you can still use windows 3.1 if you choose.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted my project and started over.  This time, it created the DbContext and Data classes in the model.  Not sure why it didn't do that before, but... alas, that's my solution.  Microsoft can't keep up with my awesomeness, so I just nuked it and started over.